# OnProvideAssistDataListener example

Tags: android, android-intent

Can someone please provide an example for a real case where I might need to use `OnProvideAssistDataListener`. I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I look at the source code, and then I look online. Someone online says

> Application.OnProvideAssistDataListener allows to place into the
>   bundle anything you would like to appear in the
>   Intent.EXTRA_ASSIST_CONTEXT part of the assist Intent

I have also been reading through the [Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an Now On Tap functionality implemented by Google. By long pressing the Home Button, you will get some  information displayed on the screen.  The information you get depends on what you're viewing on your screen at that time. (for eg: Music app displays information about music on the screen).
To provide additional information to the assistant, your app provides global application context by registering an app listener using **registerOnProvideAssistDataListener()** and supplies activity-specific information with activity callbacks by overriding **onProvideAssistData()** and **onProvideAssistContent()**. 
Now when the user activates the assistant, **onProvideAssistData(**) is called to build a full ACTION_ASSIST Intent with all of the context of the current application represented as an instance of the AssistStructure. You can override this method to place anything you like into the bundle to appear in the EXTRA_ASSIST_CONTEXT part of the assist intent.
In the example below, a music app provides structured data to describe the music album that the user is currently viewing:

```
@Override
public void onProvideAssistContent(AssistContent assistContent) {
  super.onProvideAssistContent(assistContent);

  String structuredJson = new JSONObject()
       .put("@type", "MusicRecording")
       .put("@id", "https://example.com/music/recording")
       .put("name", "Album Title")
       .toString();

  assistContent.setStructuredData(structuredJson);
}
```

For more info refer https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html